# How to access to Kafka rest proxy metrics through JMX

Tags: java, jmx, kafka-rest, jmx-exporter

I am trying to build my own metrics collector from the rest server, I need to access to a variety of metrics through JMX, to gather data, scrape and expose mBeans of the jmx server.
Like Prometheus JMX exporter.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you're not using Prometheus or Jolokia? Also, how is this question any different than any other Java process?

Answer (score 2):

You expose JMX by exporting a variable before starting it

```
export JMX_PORT=9001 # for example 
kafka-rest-start config.properties
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/blob/v5.4.1/bin/kafka-rest-run-class#L52

Similarly, rather than create your own non-industry standard solution, just use the Prometheus JMX exporter or Jolokia JMX agent and scrape it into the format you're interested in

Answer (score 0):

You can setup local/remote monitoring of kafka rest proxy using jconsole.

```sh
# local monitoring
$ jconsole <process-id-of-kafka-rest-proxy>
```

```sh
# remote monitoring
$ jconsole <host:port>
```

[image]
Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html